# View not updating with new resultset when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am building a small ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application.

When application loads, a default View is presented with a set of records. On the View, I have a panel with search filters. When user selects an option from one of the DropDown and clicks "Search", the new set of rows should be loaded.

I have added the entire functionality as below but the View is not getting updated with the new result.

**[HTML Button]**

```
<table style="margin-left:2%;margin-top:2%">
    <tr style="width:200px">
        <td style="width:100px">Location</td>
        <td style="width:300px">
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlLocation", new List<SelectListItem>
            {
               new SelectListItem{ Text="-- Select --", Value = "0" },
               new SelectListItem{ Text="North", Value = "1" },
               new SelectListItem{ Text="South", Value = "2" },
               new SelectListItem{ Text="West", Value = "3" }
            }, new { @id = "ddlLocation" })
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div style="margin: 0;position: relative;top: 30%;left:45%;right:45%">
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Filter Rows" onClick="searchRows()" />
</div>
```

**[Javascript Code]**

```
function searchRows(TemplateData) {
    var e = document.getElementById('ddlLocation');
    var FilterText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    @*var data = "@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)";*@

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Search/' + FilterText,
        type: 'GET',
        data: TemplateData,
        success: function (TemplateData) {
            $("#divData").html(TemplateData);
            alert(TemplateData);
        }
    });
}
```

**[Controller Action Method]**

```
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("~/Search/{FilterText}")]
    public IActionResult Search(string FilterText)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        List<TemplateData> templateList = new List<TemplateData>();
        templateList = ImportExcel(FilterText);
        return View(templateList.AsEnumerable());
    }
```

Please note that the 'templateList' in the above action method is fetching correct set and invoking View but the View is not updating.

I read somewhere that one Nuget Package for Runtime Compilation needs to be added. I tried to add it but it throws error: "Not compatible with ASP.NET Core 3.1".

Comment: You're doing an AJAX call but not doing anything with the results

Comment: @DavidG Could you please post modified code ? I am new to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Look at the example here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: @DavidG Added the success code as shown in that link, still not working.

Comment: @RKh, Update your question with your modified code please

Comment: @Gabe I have updated the recent JS code under Javascript section of original post.

Comment: @RKh, Do you get an error in your browser console when the AJAX call is made?

Comment: @Gabe Yes it is always going to error function when AJAX hits.

Comment: @RKh, In your API action method, you should be returning a JsonResult type. IActionResult is only for views--not AJAX.

Comment: @Gabe I changed return type. Now JS function hitting Success but View result not changing as per new model values.

Comment: @RKh, Then the issue must be in your JavaScript. What exactly are you returning from your action method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234339/discussion-between-rkh-and-gabe).

Comment: Hi @RKh, what is your main view like? Where is the element which id is divData? Also, you use `.html()` in ajax so return `View(templateList.AsEnumerable())` is correct, but you need be sure the view name is `Search.cshtml` and the model type is `IEnumerable<TemplateData>` in Search.cshtml.

Comment: @Rena I changed the return type to View("Index", templateList.AsEnumerable()). When the website opens, it is the Index view which opens. When user selects the filter and press button, I call Search action method to retrieve filtered rows and return back to the Index view. Even after changing the return type as mentioned above, View is not updating.

Comment: Hi @RKh, if you could share your whole view will be more helpful. Thanks